# Generate gps marker's icon in CSS3 for OSM

Tags: angularjs, css, openstreetmap, marker, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm generating an OpenLayer map with different markers. All is controlled with Angular and the leaflet directive.

My question : I'm wondering if it's possible to generate my marker's icons in pure CSS3 instead of using png images ?
The code which I hope to replace.

```
GPS_icon: {
            iconUrl: '/static/lib/leaflet/images/marker-gps.png',
            shadowUrl: '/static/lib/leaflet/images/marker-gps-shadow.png',
            iconSize:     [40, 40],
            shadowSize:   [40, 40],
            iconAnchor:   [20, 20],
            shadowAnchor: [18, 18],
            popupAnchor:  [10, 20]
        }
```

If somebody has already try this, I'm curious to know if it is possible and how ?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such JS webmap lib that supports CSS/font based marker icons. Feel free to ask for such a OL3 feature at their bug tracker...